# Problems when setting up a show action in Sonata Admin. Error when I was trying customize the displayed label of a show field using the label option

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am trying to set up a `showAction`. I want to customize the displayed label of a show field using "text" type for Categories in my code.
Look at my code:

```
public function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $show)
{
    $show->with("Day")
        ->add("name", "text", array("label" => "Name"))
        ->add("categories", "text", array("label" => "Categories"));
    $show->end();
}
```

This is "categories" property with getters and setters:

```
    /**
 * @var Category[]
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category\Category", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="day_category",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="day_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
 */
private $categories;


/**
 * @return Category[]
 */
public function getCategories()
{
    return $this->categories;
}

/**
 * @param Category[] $categories
 */
public function setCategories(array $categories): void
{
    $this->categories = $categories;
}
```

I want to customize the categories label with text type, but if I do this I get the error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Warning: nl2br() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given").

Here is a picture with what I want for "Categories":
[Here is what I want for categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpRO9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since **categories** is ManyToMany property, you cannot display this as text as you expect. Sonata Admin renders this field as unordered list.

You cannot use **text** type for this field. If you need to change the label, try the following.

```
public function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $show)
{
    $show->with("Day")
        ->add("name", "text", array("label" => "Name"))
        ->add("categories", null, array("label" => "Categories"));
    $show->end();
}
```

Comment: I was thinking that the type couldn’t be “text”. It’s working with NULL, but the problem is now the category can be accessed from show and you can change it by mistake. I will let it like this until I find another solution. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Sonata Admin has a template for many-to-many associations to use with `showMapper`.

You can just slightly adapt this line:

```
->add('categories', null, [
    'template' => '@SonataAdmin/CRUD/Association/show_many_to_many.html.twig'
])
```

and the associated categories will be displayed as an unordered list.

You have to provide a `__toString` method in the `Category` entity too.